# how can I scrape data in js charts

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, jscharts

I use python bs4/selenium to **scrape** and crawl webpages . I am interested about scraping this [Page](https://covid.hespress.com/). As you can see there are several js charts. But when I look at the source code, I do not find the values of the points.
How can I scrape theses values.

Answer (score 0):

That's in the javascript element `<script type="a1b007d447753b98178810e9-text/javascript">`

At some point you find something like

```
        new Chart(document.querySelector("#daily_data").getContext('2d'), {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: [1583107200000,1583193600000,1583280000000,1583366400000,1583452800000,1583539200000,1583625600000,1583712000000,1583798400000,1583884800000,1583971200000,1584057600000,1584144000000,1584230400000,1584316800000,1584403200000,1584489600000,1584576000000,1584662400000,1584748800000,1584835200000,1584921600000,1585008000000,1585094400000,1585180800000,1585267200000,1585353600000,1585440000000,1585526400000,1585612800000,1585699200000,1585785600000,1585872000000,1585958400000,1586044800000,1586131200000,1586217600000,1586304000000,1586390400000,1586476800000,1586563200000,1586649600000,1586736000000,1586822400000,1586908800000,1586995200000,1587081600000,1587168000000,1587254400000,1587340800000,1587427200000,1587513600000,1587600000000,1587686400000,1587772800000,1587859200000,1587945600000,1588032000000,1588118400000,1588204800000,1588291200000,1588377600000,1588464000000,1588550400000,1588636800000,1588723200000,1588809600000,1588896000000,1588982400000,1589068800000,1589155200000,1589241600000,1589328000000,1589414400000,1589500800000,1589587200000,1589673600000,1589760000000],
                datasets: [{
                    label: labels.cases,
                    backgroundColor: '#ffa800',
                    borderColor: '#ffa800',
                    data: [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,3,0,2,10,10,9,7,10,9,16,17,19,28,27,55,50,70,57,77,77,61,37,54,83,128,102,99,64,91,99,74,97,116,102,125,136,259,281,121,170,191,163,237,122,190,139,168,55,132,69,102,146,160,174,150,166,189,140,163,199,153,218,137,94,95,45,89,129,82]                }, {
                    label: labels.recovered,
                    backgroundColor: '#18d26b',
                    borderColor: '#18d26b',
                    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,2,1,1,1,3,1,1,2,9,5,2,26,9,10,5,12,4,12,13,24,31,26,14,12,20,32,33,13,23,43,24,39,30,51,56,102,83,150,56,99,173,182,215,185,179,162,145,137,93,257,180,140,179,90,87,173,98]                }, {
                    label: labels.deaths,
                    backgroundColor: '#ff3f3f',
                    borderColor: '#ff3f3f',
                    data: [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,4,13,2,1,7,3,3,5,4,11,11,10,10,3,4,10,4,7,8,0,1,3,5,2,4,2,2,4,6,3,1,2,1,3,3,2,1,2,1,5,2,2,0,3,0,2,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,0]                }]
            },
```

And those are your data points.
You have one Chart object for every chart on the page.

So, you could now consider reading the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/26440563/1328968